# How do I make an array for storing x, y co-ordinates from continuous user input?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently making a RobotArena game on Java and one of the tasks is to make an array for storing each robot in the game. For example, if the user wants 2 robots in the game... I'll have to store the 2 robots in an array (the x and y co ordinates of them) or if the user wants more Robots than just 2.

I've made a 2D array for the robot co ordinates but it only stores the latest X/Y co-ordinate of the robot in the array and doesn't store the previous robots co ordinate.

Is there a way to do this? Assigning it to a variable or putting it in a loop? Any answers will be appreciated.

This is the code I have so far, I'm new to Java, so I'm sorry if the code isn't too good.

```
public static class RobotArena{
    public RobotArena(int x, int y){
        int Arena[][] = new int[4][4]; //Sets the 2d array
        Arena[x][y] = '1'; //Puts 1 where the X/Y co ordinate is

        for (int[] a : Arena) { //this prints out the grid
            for (int i : a) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many Robots in your world?");
            int numRobots = s.nextInt();

            Robot[] allRobots = new Robot[numRobots];
            Robot.RobotArena[] allRobots2 = new Robot.RobotArena[numRobots];

            int rx, ry;

            System.out.println("Now enter position of each robot in turn (as x y) >");
            for (int ct = 0; ct<numRobots; ct++) {
                System.out.println("Enter, x y position for " + ct + "th robot: >");
                rx = s.nextInt();
                ry = s.nextInt();
                allRobots[ct] = new Robot(rx, ry);
                allRobots2[ct] = new RobotArena(rx, ry);
                allRobots[ct].printIdPosition(); 
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output when I add 2 robots to the game:

Co-ordinate of Robot 1 (1, 1);

```
0 0 0 0 
0 49 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

When I add the 2nd robot to the game, this is the output, with co-ord (2, 2):

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 49 0 
0 0 0 0
```

I want the 1st robot to be displayed in the latest grade too, but I'm not sure how to go round doing so.

Comment: I tried to copy all the relevant code in this question, but if you want all the necessary code then I am more than happy to add it :)

Comment: Do you have to use arrays instead of Lists ? I mean it doesn't change much, but it would make some lines easier to read.
Beside, what does RobotArena represent? a single robot?
`int Arena[][] = new int[4][4];` the name of a variable always start with a lowercase

Comment: also I don't understad why you need Robot[] allRobots and Robot.RobotArena[]? ^^'
If I were you I'd start by creating a class to represent the arena let's call it Arena. This class would store an array or a list of Robot. Each robot would contain x and y variables. Finally override the toString of your Arena class to print the grid using the list of robots to place the markers

Comment: @BrunoDelor I've checked the task and it only says to do with arrays, but a list might be easier to use?, I might try using a list! and the RobotArena represents an arena in which various robots can exist. Its attributes
should be the size of the arena in the x and y directions, an array for storing each robot, and oh thank you!

Comment: well I don;t want to make you fail your assignment so let's stick to arrays it's fine ;p

Comment: So you want 49 to be displayed at 1,1 and 2,2? How do you plan to manage the case where both robots are at the same co-ordinates?

Comment: @VidorVistrom yes, I want both of them to display at once in the same grid but I can’t figure out how to do it and oh I haven’t started planning that yet, but maybe through an If statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather do it this way:

• Use only one variable to initialize all robots

• Use a private member to initialize Arena

• Make a method that would set Co-ordinates

• Make a method that would print the Arena.

```
public static class RobotArena{
    int Arena[][] = new int[4][4];


public void setCoordinates(int x,int y){
    Arena[x][y] = '1';
}
public void printArena(){
     for (int[] a : Arena) { //this prints out the grid
        for (int i : a) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many Robots in your world?");
        int numRobots = s.nextInt();

       RobotArena allRobots=new RobotArena();

        int rx, ry;

        System.out.println("Now enter position of each robot in turn (as x y) >");
        for (int ct = 0; ct<numRobots; ct++) {
            System.out.println("Enter, x y position for " + ct + "th robot: >");
            rx = s.nextInt();
            ry = s.nextInt();
            allRobots.setCoordinates(rx, ry);

            //allRobots[ct].printIdPosition(); 
        }
        allRobots.printArena();
    }
```

Comment: ohhh Thank you so much! That has solved the issue I had! I didn't really think about doing it like that! i've been stuck on this problem for a while now! The solution you've proposed has done exactly the thing I wanted it to do, so thank you very much!

Comment: @j.Dixon no problem at all. Glad it helped